# Changing a TableView cell colour will not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

Trying to change the `UITableViewCell` text `UIColour` (costume cell) will make the text become white and unseen, than only when touching the `UITableViewCell`, I can see the text .
Why setting `UIColour` to a `UITableViewCell` that is not `blackColor` will not work ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = 
     [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];       
    if (!indexPath.row) {
        NSDictionary *dic= [[GlobalData sharedGlobals].categories 
                             objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        cell.textLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"title"]; // only top row showing
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" 
                                              size:22];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:177 
                                                   green:218 
                                                    blue:229 
                                                   alpha:1];
        //cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:218 
                                                           green:241 
                                                            blue:245 
                                                           alpha:1];
    } else {
       NSMutableArray *typesOfSection = 
        [[GlobalData sharedGlobals].typesByCategories 
          objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSDictionary *type = [typesOfSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        NSString *titleOfType = [type objectForKey:@"title"];
        cell.textLabel.text = titleOfType;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:122 
                                                   green:181 
                                                    blue:196 
                                                   alpha:1];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" 
                                              size:22];

        //cell.textLabel.text = @"check";
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And when doing this :

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

its working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically setting the cell's text colour to white. The RGB values should be between 0.0 and 1.0.

Try this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:122.0/255.0 green:181.0/255.0 blue:196.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: thanks but this colours only the first cells that are occupied. there are more cells which are empty-they stay white

Comment: You probably want to change the other colour too. Try this [UIColor colorWithRed:177.0/255.0 green:218.0/255.0 blue:229.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 1):

Use this
You did not add .0f(float) behind each parameter by which you are not getting cell textcolor.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:122.0f/255.0f green:181.0f/255.0f blue:196 .0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```